# How do you correctly get a value out of an Object and add it to another value | Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I'm pretty new to Angular and try to create a taxi-booking app.
So far everything is working as intended, but I have to implement a price calculator based on vehicle-price and tarif so that two-way-binding {{price}} shows the user the correct amount

the vehicle has a type of number (0,5,20) but the tarif is an json-object
    zipValue = { view:'1010 - Innere Stadt', value: 24 }

my solution so far was populating a variable with vehicle and add the object.value

```
price = this.zipValue.value + this.price
```

Angular is throwing me an error that Property 'value' does not exist on type 'object'

How do I calculate this correctly without errors?

**Sample Code:
app-component.html**

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Passagiere</mat-label>
    <mat-select name="passengers" ngModel [(value)]='passengersAmount'>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let p of passengers" [value]="p.value">
            {{p.view}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Gepäckstücke</mat-label>
        <mat-select name="luggage" ngModel [(value)]='luggage'>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let s of pieces" [value]="s.value">
            {{s.view}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

<mat-select placeholder="Postleitzahl" [(ngModel)]="zipValue" name="zip">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let z of zip" [value]="z" >{{z.view}}</mat-option>
 </mat-select>

<button (click)="calculate();">name</button>
</form>
```

**Sample Code: app.component.ts**

```js
export class FormDeComponent {

  //
  // Dynamic Objects for SELECT
  //

  passengers = [
    { value: 1, view: '1 Person' },
    { value: 2, view: '2 Personen' },
    { value: 3, view: '3 Personen' },
    { value: 4, view: '4 Personen' },
    { value: 5, view: '5 Personen' }
  ];

  pieces = [
    { value: 0, view: 'Keine' },
    { value: 1, view: '1 Stück' },
    { value: 2, view: '2 Stück' },
    { value: 3, view: '3 Stück' },
    { value: 4, view: '4 Stück' },
    { value: 5, view: '5 Stück' },
];

  zip = [
    { view: '1010 - Innere Stadt', value: 24 },
    { view: '1020 - Leopoldstadt', value: 27 },
    { view: '1030 - Landstraße', value: 29 }
  ];

  mod = [0, 5, 20]

  passengersAmount: number;
  luggage: number;
  price: number;
  zipValue: object;

  calculate() {
    if (this.passengersAmount <=3 && this.luggage <= 3) { this.price = this.mod[0] }
    else if (this.passengersAmount <=4 && this.luggage <= 4) { this.price = this.mod[1] }
    else {this.price = this.mod[2]}
    this.price = this.zipValue.value + this.price; 
  }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
      console.log(form.value);
    }

  }
```

Comment: It would be great if you'd add some samples to elaborate your concern

Comment: how are you turning your JSON into an object?  Are you implementing it against an interface?

Comment: We cant explain why your code doesn't compile and how to fix it if you don't post it. A single line of code is not suficient.

Comment: I added my code and shorted it to the basics, so you can recreate my problem. I've restarted the server and now it doesn't compile at all, Safari says: ```Cannot get / ``` pretty weird @Piyush @BlairHolmes @JBNizet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```js
zipValue: object;
```

To this:

```js
zipValue: {view: string, value: number};
```

You can define interfaces as inline types in TypeScript. The above is the same as doing the following.

```js
interface ZipCode {
   view: string;
   value: number;
}

zip: ZipCode[] = [
  { view: '1010 - Innere Stadt', value: 24 },
  { view: '1020 - Leopoldstadt', value: 27 },
  { view: '1030 - Landstraße', value: 29 }
];

zipValue: ZipCode;
```

I prefer the second approach over the first approach.

Comment: I never thought of that :/ I will try that! Thank you! But how could your 2nd approach work when i‘d want to load zip from a database later on? Isn’t it then just easier to interface it inline?

Comment: Interfaces don't carry any weight in the JavaScript compiled output. They are just types used by TypeScript. So start with inline, but if you're finding yourself repeating it often then make it a declared interface.

Comment: @David your db call I assume is going through an API: subscribe to an `Observable<ZipCode[]>` and pipe your data accordingly.

Comment: **You're a Hero!** It finally works! I guess I should read more about interfaces, as `zipValue.value` would be the standard js way. No interfaces whatsoever. Thank you!

Comment: @David if you get stuck `zipValue: any` disables TypeScript's type checking.

Comment: Thank you both! Reactgular & BlairHolmes ! **You're a hero** for a dumb 16yo web-development student like me! Angular might be complicated at first, but I'm slowly getting it :)